# Why wont the group_by() function in R work properly?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a large dataframe and I am trying to sort by 8 categories in one column and then find the sum of their weight (kg) using the group_by() and summarise() functions from dplyr package.

However, in the 'total' variable created, the sums of some of the categories produce N/A and I'm not sure why as they should be numerical values. There isn't anything weird about the dataframe which I can see.

code:

```
totals <- db %>% group_by(category) %>% summarise(kilos = sum(weight))
```

Comment: Sounds like your data have some missing values. Try using `sum(weight, na.rm = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1):

sum function does not work with NA values. Specify the na.rm argument as TRUE and it will ignore the NA values. Below should work:

```
enter code here totals <- db %>% 
group_by(category) %>% 
summarise(kilos = sum(weight,na.rm =TRUE))
```